# R: Improving Implementation Simple Model

Tags: r, loops, iteration

I have coded a simple numerical example (which I will make more complex later on). You have two substances A and B. At every round (i.e. iteration of a process), they consume each other at rate r.
I have something which works (see the reprex below), but it is rather ugly. First of all, it relies explicitly on a loop (perhaps there is a solution with map), then there are two variables containing the initial state which get overwritten.

Finally, there is ***one stopping condition***: substances A and B cannot take negative values, so as soon as that happens, the process has to stop.
Please look at the reprex at the end of the post.
Any suggestion for improvement is welcome.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

A <- 2000
B <- 1000 ## initial quantities of A and B

r <- 1/10 ## consumption rate

n_rounds <- 10 ## how many iterations

consumption_round <- function(ab_vec,r){ ## function determining how much
 ## A and B decreas at each round

    A1 <- ab_vec[1]-ab_vec[2]*r
    B1 <- ab_vec[2]-ab_vec[1]*r

    res <- c(A1, B1)

    return(res)
}


AB <- c(A,B) ## initial state


ini <- AB

list_res <- AB  ## other variables storing the initial state which will be overwritten ## I would like a better way to do this


for (i in seq(n_rounds)){

    print("i is,")
    print(i)
    
    output <- consumption_round(ini, r)

    ini <- output

    list_res <- rbind(list_res, output)
    
}
#> [1] "i is,"
#> [1] 1
#> [1] "i is,"
#> [1] 2
#> [1] "i is,"
#> [1] 3
#> [1] "i is,"
#> [1] 4
#> [1] "i is,"
#> [1] 5
#> [1] "i is,"
#> [1] 6
#> [1] "i is,"
#> [1] 7
#> [1] "i is,"
#> [1] 8
#> [1] "i is,"
#> [1] 9
#> [1] "i is,"
#> [1] 10

sim_res <- list_res |>
    as_tibble(.name_repair="unique") |>
    rename("A"="...1",
           "B"="...2") |>
    mutate(B=if_else(B>=0, B, 0)) |> ## B cannot be negative
    slice(1:min(which(B==0))) ## As soon as B is zero, the simulation ends.
#> New names:
#> • `` -> `...1`
#> • `` -> `...2`

sim_res
#> # A tibble: 7 × 2
#>       A      B
#>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 2000  1000  
#> 2 1900   800  
#> 3 1820   610  
#> 4 1759   428  
#> 5 1716.  252. 
#> 6 1691.   80.5
#> 7 1683.    0
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I don't understand your model. What does "consume each other" mean? Your model is clearly wrong if it can result in negative concentrations. Proper reaction kinetics don't do that.

Comment: Indeed I should have a stopping condition. Let's skip discussions about reaction kinetics. I just want a more elegant way of doing what I am already doing.

Comment: No, you are misunderstanding my comment. You shouldn't need a stopping condition because the equation should be `ab_vec[1]-ab_vec[1]*k` with first order kinetics.

Comment: look, I do not want to go on with this. I made a reference to two substances consuming each other but this is a poor man's model of the attrition between two armies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Iteration With Termination

If you want to have some termination criteria, you can try

```
AB <- cbind(A, B)
r <- 1 / 10
alpha <- (1 + r) * diag(2) + matrix(-r, 2, 2)
res <- AB
repeat {
    if (min(AB) == 0) break
    AB <- AB %*% alpha
    res <- rbind(res, pmax(AB, 0))
}
```

or using `svd` to have SVD decomposition

```
AB <- cbind(A, B)
r <- 1 / 10
alpha <- (1 + r) * diag(2) + matrix(-r, 2, 2)
X <- svd(alpha)
res <- AB
k <- 1
repeat {
    v <- AB %*% with(X, u %*% diag(d^k) %*% t(v))
    res <- rbind(res, pmax(v, 0))
    if (min(v) <= 0) {
        break
    }
    k <- k + 1
}
```

such that

```
> res
            A       B
[1,] 2000.000 1000.00
[2,] 1900.000  800.00
[3,] 1820.000  610.00
[4,] 1759.000  428.00
[5,] 1716.200  252.10
[6,] 1690.990   80.48
[7,] 1682.942    0.00
```

---

## Iteration Without Termination

You can try `Reduce` like below, where the matrix `alpha` is used to update the values of `A` and `B`, iteratively

```
AB <- cbind(A, B)
r <- 1 / 10
alpha <- (1 + r) * diag(2) + matrix(-r, 2, 2)
do.call(
    rbind,
    Reduce(`%*%`, rep(list(alpha), 10), init = AB, accumulate = TRUE)
)
```

which gives

```
             A         B
 [1,] 2000.000 1000.0000
 [2,] 1900.000  800.0000
 [3,] 1820.000  610.0000
 [4,] 1759.000  428.0000
 [5,] 1716.200  252.1000
 [6,] 1690.990   80.4800
 [7,] 1682.942  -88.6190
 [8,] 1691.804 -256.9132
 [9,] 1717.495 -426.0936
[10,] 1760.105 -597.8431
[11,] 1819.889 -773.8536
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution. I will also look for a tidyverse approach, but you definitely answered my question.

Comment: Just for the record, the same result as in iteration without termination can be achieved also with the excellent purrr package:  accumulate(rep(list(alpha), 10), `%*%`, .init=AB ) .

Comment: @larry77 yes, `accumulate` works in the same mechanism as `Reduce`